# Bootstrap 3 - confused about including .less files into my app

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm wondering if its okay to import all of `bootstrap.less` into my own .less file and then overriding anything I wish to change within that one file. My own .less file, `style.less`, outputs everything into a single style sheet, and I'm NOT including the compiled `bootstrap.css` file, only the JS files.

```
bootstrap // folder with all bootstrap less files.
style.less // imports bootstrap folder, and outputs style.css in root directory
```

Are there any drawbacks to doing it like this, or should I also be including the compiled `bootstrap.css` file?

Comment: Make sure you import the default boostrap less files in the same order that the bootstrap.less file does, or you may run into some rules not cascading properly

Comment: I'm importing `bootstrap.less` which itself imports all of the default bootstrap less files so I don't think that is a problem, or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: It should be ok then, but you may run into issues with their built in utility classes not working because they don't come last.  I usually just add my own less imports to the bootstrap.less file itself where I feel appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, do, you immediately gain access to all the mix-ins and variables.  I'd say this is the most powerful way to use bootstrap.

As you're suggesting just import bootstrap.less at the head of your less file.  I import any other mixin libraries, like lesshat, after that.

The problem is that you end up with one monolithic CSS file which is a nightmare to debug, but less.js 1.50 introduces source maps which is invaluable when using this methodology: http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/12/28/debug-less-with-chrome-developer-tools/

A faff to set up but saves a lot of head scratching.